# Passing value from JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Passing a table cell value from javascript variable into php variable.

```js
<script>
  $(document).on('ready',function(){
    $('#business_list_table').on('click','.view_btn',function (){
      $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      method: "POST",
      data:{business_id : "6510-1"},
      success: function (data){
        $('#business_permit_table').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

```html
<?php
$business_id = $_GET["business_id"];
echo $business_id;
```

Comment: what do you mean "pass value from JS to PHP"? You can't do that

Comment: You have SQL injection and XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: I don't see any injection vulnerability. Only XSS. The only query I see is a static string: `SELECT * FROM business_tb WHERE Business_ID='<script>document.writeln(Business_ID)</script>'`

Comment: I think you're mixing up server-side code (PHP) and client side JavaScript which runs in the user's browser only after the PHP code has output the HTML and JavaScript. If you want to send another HTTP request to your server from client side code you should look into ajax.

Comment: i just directly used select to shorten the code but the actual i converted it to json.

Comment: i tried to directly put a value <script> var sample = '6510-1'; </script> <?php $sample = "<script>document.writeln(sample)</script>"; echo $sample; it works fine but when i tried to get a vlue from a table cell it echo's undefine

Comment: That's the same as doing  `<?php echo '<script>document.writeln(sample)</script>'; ?>`. You're outputting a script and then when that script runs client side it prints the value of `sample`.

Comment: Try running `echo "<pre>$sample</pre>";` You can't run client-side JavaScript on your server, you can only output scripts that then run in the browser.

Comment: so what's the correct way sir?what can you advice?

Comment: Do some reading up on "ajax". You can use it to make additional  HTTP requests to your server from client-side JavaScript. You can send any data you want from the browser that way.

Comment: okay sir thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: i'd used ajax and my problem was solved. thanks @Paulpro.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear that you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use JS variable directly to PHP like that. use ajax instead:

JS

```
$("#business_list_table").on('click', '.view_btn', function post() {
    // get the current row
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var Business_id_value= currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // get current row 2nd T;

    $.post('', {Business_ID: Business_id_value}, function(result){
        $('table tbody').html(result);
    });

});
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['Business_ID'])) {
    $Business_ID = $_POST['Business_ID'];

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bpsystem");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Database connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM business_tb WHERE Business_ID='$Business_ID';";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr >";
                echo "<td>BUSINESS NAME</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Business_Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr >";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate that you have explained the problem instead of just putting code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query string to pass the variable to PHP. Like this,

```
$("#business_list_table").on('click', '.view_btn', function post() {
    // get the current row
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var Business_id_value= currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // get current row 2nd T;
    window.location.href = 'http://your_url?b_id=' + Business_id_value;

});
```

Now you can access the  *Business_id_value* varible in your PHP script using `$_GET['Business_id_value']`